# Visual Basic Textbox number of lines

Tags: vb.net

In VB.NET, I want to find out how many whole lines of text I could fit inside a multiline textbox. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that the WPF TextBox controls don't have a Multiline property, this is presumably for a WinForms application.

To determine how much text you can fit in a given size (the dimensions of the TextBox control)  I would suggest using the [TextRenderer.MeasureText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext.aspx) method to determine the height of a single character.  Divide the height of the TextBox control by the height of the character to get the number of lines visible at one time.

Keep in mind that the measurements of characters may potentially differ in so much that the measurement of an asterisk (*) may be very small, whereas the measurement of an octothorpe (#) may be much larger.  The MSDN page seems to state however, that this is a non-issue as long as you use `MeasureText(String, Font)` and not any of the other overloads.